# Inputting liquid species in chemkin pro

Tags: reaction-mechanism, software

I have been trying to model various species decomposition/combustion in Chemkin Pro.

Chemkin only lets you to allow to input gas phase and surface site solid species in your input files, but I have various fuels/propellants in liquid state whose decomposition/combustion I need to model.

Is there any way to input liquid species reaction mechanism's in Chemkin by inputting them as gas species but somehow manipulating the Arrhenius coefficients, so that the software will ultimately model the liquid species in question?

Also if there's some other way to accomplish this instead of manipulating Arrhenius coefficients, I would be grateful for the input